# Calculo valor com Virgula com Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js, matemática

Boa tarde, o Vue.JS consegue calcular direto no mustache {{}} porém quando um valor vem com virgula, aparece NaN o resultado
ou seja, se a variável for valor = 2 e eu fizer {{ valor - 1 }} ele exibe 1 de boa mas se eu fizer valor = 2,5 e então {{ valor - 1 }} ele exibe NaN

```
<p>{{ valor - 2 }}</p>
```

como eu poderia calcular este valor de virgula nos mustaches?

Comment: É só a vírgula que você precisa tratar mesmo? Que tipo de valores você quer aceitar nesse campos? Vale `1.500`, `R$ 1.500,00`, `1,6%` etc?

Comment: Poderia usar o valor bruto para cálculo e um filter para exibição, daí não teria necessidade de tratar a vírgula

Comment: @bfavaretto sim, a virgula, é bem básico, a variável recebe 4,5 e preciso mostrar 3,5 na verdade

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza é que o valor bruto é 4,5

Comment: Você poderia utilizar a função `replace`, ex: `number.replace(',', '.')`, porém vai retornar uma `String`, o que pode causar comportamentos estranhos

Comment: Se `valor` é uma string não faz sentido algum fazer cálculos com a variável nos mustaches. Só vai tornar seu código obscuro e/ou gerar gambiarras. A variável `valor` deveria ser do tipo `float`, quem fará essa conversão depende de você, mas nos mustaches não rola...

Comment: @fernandosavio é que é uma informação no topo da página que desejo repetir em vários lugares porém em 1 lugar ela precisa subtrair um certo valor, sei que é obscuro e bizarro, é que não domino, estou estudando e me deparei com esta lacuna

Comment: Então nesse lugar específico você pode fazer a conversão, calcular e depois converter de volta para string. Pode fazer fazer isso no `methods()` se quiser.

Comment: @fernandosavio então eu iria lá onde está o method() ou criar um que recebe a Virgula, troca para Ponto e return com Virgula, seria isso?

Comment: Vou postar um exemplo, poderia ser com `method` com `filter`, vai de ti mesmo

Comment: @fernandosavio muito valew amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o **bfavaretto** já mencionou você pode trocar a vírgula por ponto para o JS fazer a conversão automática para Number quando for feita a subtração.

Mas você poderia ter uma função para converter esta string para Float e outra função para formatar o Float para String. Depois é só usar estar funções para trabalhar com seus dados. Aí como você aplica no seu código você escolhe!

No código abaixo coloquei exemplos com [Filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html), [Computed Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) e *Methods*.

```js
let toFloat = str => parseFloat(str.replace(',', '.'));
let toStr = float => ("" + float).replace('.', ',');


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    valor: "2,5",
  },
  filters: {
    sub2(value) {
      let number = toFloat(value) - 2;
      return toStr(number);
    },
  },
  computed: {
      valor_sub2() {
        let number = toFloat(this.valor) - 2;
        return toStr(number);
      },
  },
  methods: {
    method_sub2(value) {
      let number = toFloat(value) - 2;
      return toStr(number);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="valor">
  <div>Filter: {{ valor }} - 2 = {{ valor | sub2 }}</div>
  <div>Computed: {{ valor }} - 2 = {{ valor_sub2 }}</div>
  <div>Method: {{ valor }} - 2 = {{ method_sub2(valor) }}</div>
</div>
```

---

Não entrei no mérito da internacionalização de números por não ser parte do seu problema, mas esta técnica de usar `String.replace()` só serve para inputs muito restritos. Se você quer que o usuário digite um número e o seu software reconheça é preciso trabalhar melhor o *parsing* destas strings. No meu exemplo seriam os métodos `toFloat()` e `toStr()`. (Dica de leitura: [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat))

Comment: agradeço demais e irei estudar as referencias citadas, realmente estou precisando estudar estes method e coputed

Answer (score 5):

Troque a vírgula por ponto:

```
<p>{{ valor.replace(',', '.') - 2 }}</p>
```

Recomendo criar uma propriedade computada do Vue e fazer o replace lá, para não sujar sua view.

Outra coisa, isso vai funcionar para subtração, multiplicação e divisão, mas adição será tratada como concatenação de strings, conforme [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342116/calculo-valor-com-virgula-com-vue-js/342126#comment689751_342116) acima pelo Denis Rudnei de Souza. Para somar, você precisa ainda converter em número:

```
+valor.replace(',', '.')
```

ou

```
parseFloat(valor.replace(',', '.'))
```

Comment: realmente, funciona mesmo para subtrair, agora neste caso eu teria que criar um Filter? pois o problema é que no final ele escreve com . ou seja, entra 4,5 e sai 3.5 neste caso a virgula virou ponto no resultado final, calculou mas virou ponto, e esta propriedade computada realmente seria o melhor a fazer, só não sei exatamente o que seria ainda, estou começando a fuçar

Comment: Opa @flourigh, só vi agora. Acho que a resposta do fernandosavio esclarece suas dúvidas. No fundo você precisa de lugares separados para tratar os cálculos em si e as entradas/saídas formatadas com vírgula.